# check for empty cel and then count the value in the column and paste it to another sheet

Tags: vba, excel

I am having two sht, sht1 as BW and sht2 as result.

I want to Count the number of 1's in column T and U of sht1, according to the week in column AX and print the Counted values in the result sheet, looking into the same week.

I took the advice of an expert in the Forum and completed till this.

I want an if condition, in such a way that, if the column AA is empty, then i should not Count the 1's in column T and U, it should be skipped.

I introduced this code of line in my existing code after j=2;  and got an error

> error Label not defined`,

```
 If ws.Range("AA" & i) = "" Then 
GoTo nextrow
```

could someone help, how i should execute this condition ?
here is my code;

```
Sub results()

Dim i As Integer, j As Integer, cntT As Integer, cntu As Integer, ws As Worksheet
Set ws = Sheets("Result")
Sheets("BW").Select
For i = 2 To WorksheetFunction.CountA(ws.Columns(1))
cntT = 0
cntu = 0
If ws.Range("A" & i) = Val(Format(Now, "ww")) Then Exit For
Next i

For j = 2 To WorksheetFunction.CountA(Columns(50))

If ws.Range("A" & i) = Range("AX" & j) And Range("T" & j) = 1 Then cntT = cntT + 1
If ws.Range("A" & i) = Range("AX" & j) And Range("U" & j) = 1 Then cntu = cntu + 1

Next j
If cntT <> 0 Then ws.Range("B" & i) = cntT
If cntu <> 0 Then ws.Range("C" & i) = cntu
If cntT + cntu <> 0 Then
ws.Range("D" & i) = cntT + cntu
ws.Range("E" & i) = cntT / (cntT + cntu)
ws.Range("F" & i) = cntu / (cntT + cntu)
End If
ws.Range("E" & i & ":F" & i).NumberFormat = "0%"
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

The `GoTo nextrow` is looking for a line label titled `nextrow`.  That's how the GoTo command is built and operates.  For what you are trying to accomplish, try this instead:

```
If ws.Range("AA" & i) <> "" Then 
    If ws.Range("A" & i) = Range("AX" & j) And Range("T" & j) = 1 Then cntT = cntT + 1
    If ws.Range("A" & i) = Range("AX" & j) And Range("U" & j) = 1 Then cntu = cntu + 1
End If
```

This way it says, if the column is *NOT* blank, then `do stuff`, otherwise go to `next j`

If you want to use the GoTo Command in the future you can use line numbers (like `GoTo 0` which should take you back to the beginning of the code) or you can create a line label by placing `nextrow:` on an empty line.  Then when you call `GoTo nextrow` it will go to that line, and proceed from there.

Comment: Thank you for the Response. End if should be  before the last line ? am i correct ?

Comment: i mean, before ths line ? ws.Range("E" & i & ":F" & i).NumberFormat = "0%"

Comment: If i Do like yours, then i am not able to print the values in my result sht

Comment: I put the End If after your If statements which increase your count variables. By placing it right after those statements, the only thing that won't happen if the column is blank is it won't try to count things in those columns, then it will continue and check the next J. If you put it later in the code, it will skip past everything else and potentially error since it won't pick up the `next j`

Comment: So, how do i do ? @busse

Comment: By end if , before nextj , it is not printing the values in sht2.